# Get numerical data from a text file?

Tags: python

I need to change the code in line `# 20`. That is,  need in the line

```
B = 852854485224
```

add code so that the script takes this number from a test file called **"List.txt"**. But I have other numbers (i.e. a list of numbers).
I have approximately seen scripts that use `with open ("List.txt", "r") as f:` take data from a text document.

I have a list of **"List.txt"**

```
852854485224
582721123530
601004166698
849500094741
864974296510
674088523501
685133919924
....
...
..
.
```

Need to add a function so that the script takes data from the list of the document **"List.txt"** and the whole result was saved in one document **"Save.txt"**

```
import random2
 
def extended_gcd(aa, bb):
    lastremainder, remainder = abs(aa), abs(bb)
    x, lastx, y, lasty = 0, 1, 1, 0
    while remainder:
        lastremainder, (quotient, remainder) = remainder, divmod(lastremainder, remainder)
        x, lastx = lastx - quotient*x, x
        y, lasty = lasty - quotient*y, y
    return lastremainder, lastx * (-1 if aa < 0 else 1), lasty * (-1 if bb < 0 else 1)
 
def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = extended_gcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise ValueError
    return x % m
 

A = 963388677994
B = 852854485224


with open("Save.txt", "a") as f:
    for _ in range(100):
        W = random2.randrange(16**6)
        val = str(hex((A*B*W)))
        if len(val) < 66:
            vals = val.split('x')
            vals.insert(1, 'x' + '0' * (66-len(val)))
            val = ''.join(vals)
        print(val, file=f)
```